# Scroll issue on Firefox vs Webkit browsers - Side navigation, text truncate and scroll

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with scrollbar appearance on different browsers. In my example I would like to properly show truncated text inside side-navigation component but it is displayed incorrectly on Firefox/IE browsers.

[image]

Check out this fiddle on both Chrome and Firefox (code is not in the post since it takes up a lot of space):

https://jsfiddle.net/d84b9m49/10/

As you can see, the issue is positioning of the scrollbar in Webkit browsers in comparison to Firefox/IE, apparently Firefox displays scrollbar inside right padding area (total of 65px (width is set to 65px in style)) and Chrome displays scrollbar outside right padding area (total of 85px (65px + scrollbar width). In **Firefox**, when scrollbar appears, the content of the `li` item appears **not centered** and the part of the text is displayed below scrollbar (and horizontal scrollbar appears) and on **Chrome** everything looks correct (everything is **centered**). Also, the *documentation* describes this difference in handling scrollbar (ISSUE 1):

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#scrollable

The previous solution involved using `max-width: 65px` (check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mkfg20o/3/)) but this is not an option since, if there is only short text, the width of side navigation will shrink and the width should not change because of the text ( maybe there is some easy fix for this problem? )

Please do not disregard the layout of the navigation component on smaller devices, below 768px (on the provided example it becomes "bottom" navigation).

I would like to make the items inside navigation component **centered** in both Chrome and Firefox, let's ignore IE for now.

Can someone help me with this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** For future reference, you can choose any of the upvoted answers below depending on your requirements (either go with the *scroll check* approach, or just *remove scrollbars* and add some arrows to scroll the content).

Comment: Tough one to crack... That puzzles me! Is it mandatory to you that the scrollbar disappears if the window's height is enough to display the full navbar? I assume it is ;)

Comment: Hi, I have noticed that `overflow: scroll` works, but unfortunately it is mandatory for scrollbar to disappear when there is enough space. :( On the other hand, it is interesting that `overflow: scroll` properly positions `scrollbar` on `non-webkit` browsers (on the right), but `overflow: auto` does not. I guess there is more to scrollbars than what it looks like.

Comment: its default behavior of browsers. If it is ok use `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;}` to hide scrollbar

Comment: @Znaneswar Yes, I may be forced to hide `scrollbar` and to use some different approach, at least until scrollbar is properly handled on all browsers...

Comment: Write media-queries and hide scrollbar when width `<65px`

Comment: @miselking have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: @Znaneswar Yes I have, it is still not perfect for my requirements but I will accept it and reward it; it kinda solves my problem but unfortunately I must be able to add/remove elements at any time so I will have to check `scroll height` vs `height` more often (and `Angular` is not that friendly with these `DOM` checks). Anyways, I decided to change the UI and just move on until such time this is actually fixed. Still, thank you and keep up the good work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment, You can directly hide scrollbar by

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;}
```

or calculate width of scrollbar by using `JQuery` and add same margin to body/container.

Try code something like this

```
var checkScrollBars = function(){
    var normalwidth = 0;
    var scrollwidth = 0;
    if($('body').prop('scrollHeight')>$('body').height()){
        normalwidth = window.innerWidth;
        scrollwidth = normalwidth - $('body').width();
        $('#container').css({marginRight:'-'+scrollwidth+'px'});
    }
}
```

and for horizontal scrollbar

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

**EDIT**

from your comment, if you think its performance overhead calculate scrollbar width only once and add it by default on page load.

Check this way..

```
function scrollbarWidth() { 
    var div = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div>'); 
    // Append our div, do our calculation and then remove it 
    $('body').append(div); 
    var w1 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
    div.css('overflow-y', 'scroll'); 
    var w2 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
    $(div).remove(); 
    return (w1 - w2); 
}
```

Or call these functions(above two) only if the inner width lessthan some `<80px` like this

```
if ($(window).width() < 85px) {
   //your function
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes, that is one of the possible solutions (although I use `Angular 4` and not `jQuery` but I know how to write this check in Angular). The only potential problem I see is the performance overhead since I will have to check `scrollHeight` against `height` a lot (when items are added, removed, window height is modified, etc.) and that could cause performance issues. Anyways, thank you for your answer, and I will accept this answer and give you bounty reward if there is no better solution in the next couple of days.

Comment: Updated my answer to make it a bit simpler. Check once

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the scrollbar.

```
.nav.navbar.navbar-inverse::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
.nav.navbar.navbar-inverse { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
.nav.navbar.navbar-inverse { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

Check it on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d84b9m49/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Its issue with Firefox scroll bar, We can fix this issue adding `padding-right: 18px` (which is scroll width) to the overflow-y element, Example

```
.navbar {
    padding: 0;
    background:  #283030;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right:18px;
}
li.nav-item {
  width: 65px;
}
```

you can set 65px width now...

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Yes, it seems that there is no proper standard for handling scrollbar on different browsers, and as `padding-right` may seem as a good solution, it looks weird on `webkit` browsers (Chrome - extra space on the right), and, if there is no scrollbar (small amount of items) it also has that weird space that padding created. I may be forced to abort this `scrollbar` approach, and completely redesign this component...